# Prevent controller input to unwanted process

Tags: controllers, windows-10, dolphin-emulator

I often have a game running in the background while I play something on dolphin. The particular game does not seem to listen to unbinding / not being in the foreground. Any utility specifically for windows to force it to play ball?

Comment: Recommendations are off-topic, but I dont think you are _specifically_ looking for some software or utility to fix this, rather just *a way* that might just so happen to involve software.

Comment: Which gamepad are you using? I'm not sure how to solve this for XInput but if it's a HID gamepad you could try using HidHide to selectively block specific apps from accessing the gamepad: https://github.com/ViGEm/HidHide

Comment: @TimmyJim yeah you'rer right just looking for a solution to a bad acting piece of software. To nondebug honestly not entirely sure im not familiar with the internals here. Im using an Xbox One X wireless (bluetooth) controller. I have an older Xbox one controller too but not using it as much since i need to repair one of its buttons and i need to get the right sized torx driver